# How to send query result to stored procedure correctly?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables. I want to compare the number of rows in table a to a value in table b:

```
select count(1) from table_a; -- returns 1500
select some_var from table_b; -- returns 1490
```

I want to compare the numbers and perform and write a line into `table c` accordingly. `tabel_c` is sort of an auditlog, which is filled via stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.audit_log (
  @query varchar(100)
, @result varchar(100) 
) as
insert into [table_c] (finished, query, result) 
values (getdate(), @query, @result)
```

I'm comparing the values from `table_a` and `table_b` as follows:

```
select 
    case when (select count(1) from table_a) != (select row_count from table_b) 
         then 'Values do not match' else 'Values match'
    end
```

My question is how to add the result of the query to the audit log (`table_c`). I'm trying:

```
exec dbo.audit_log 'Compare values from 2 tables', (
    select 
        case when (select count(1) from table_a) != (select row_count from table_b)                  then 'Values do not match' else 'Values match' 
        end
    )
```

However, this does not work: `Incorrect syntax near '('`

**Question** What is the correct systax to het the values `Compare values from 2 tables` and `Values do not match` added to the audit log?

Comment: similar to your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034152/how-to-compare-a-count-to-a-value-from-another-table

Comment: You already have two answers for this in your other question and you are rude enough to simply ask more questions AND post another duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @table_a as table (
id int
)
insert into @table_a values (1)

declare @table_b as table (
row_count int
)
insert into @table_b values (1)

declare @out varchar(max);

select @out = 
case when (select count(1) from @table_a) != (select row_count from @table_b) 
then 'Values do not match' else 'Values match'
end

exec dbo.audit_log 'Compare values from 2 tables', @out
```

This will work for you. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

taking my last answer:

```
declare @valueA int
      , @valueB int
      , @msg    varchar(50);

SELECT @valueA = a.value_a
     , @valueB = b.value_b
     , @msg  = case
       when value_a = b.value_b then 'values do match'
       else 'values do not match'
       end
FROM
( select count(*)  value_a from table_a) a ,
( select row_count value_b from table_b) b;

select @valueA va, @valueB vb, @msg msg;

if (@valueA <> @valueB)
  exec dbo.audit_log @msg, @valueA, @valueB;
```